# In Cesium, how can I auto trigger click event without mouse click?

Tags: javascript, cesiumjs

I want to make a query function for 3d tile. When i search a tile, the tile's contour will highlight (like 3D Tiles Feature Picking Demo). In Cesium demo, they pick a tile feature by mouse click event, but i don't want to pick a tile feature by mouse click. I want to give pick function a value (for example: viewer.scene.pick(Cesium.Cartesian2(309,306));), then i can get that tile.
In Cesium, how can I auto trigger click event without mouse click when I want to pick a 3d tile feature ? If no, how should I do?

Comment: I don't think faking a mouse event is what you want here.  The [Picking Demo](https://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Apps/Sandcastle/?src=3D%20Tiles%20Feature%20Picking.html) shows various ways to select and highlight a particular 3D tile feature.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I didn't say my problem clearly. I want to make a query function for 3d tile. When i search a tile, the tile's contour will highlight (like 3D Tiles Feature Picking Demo). In Cesium demo, they pick a tile feature by mouse click event, but i don't want to pick a tile feature by mouse click. I want to give pick function a value (for example: viewer.scene.pick(Cesium.Cartesian2(309,306));), then i can get that tile. Can anyone give me some advice? thanks.

Comment: Hi @Cherry, recommended practice for StackOverflow is to edit your original question to include additional clarifications, rather than losing them in a thread of comments below.  Can you make those edits?  Also, your sample should work, it's just missing the `new` keyword:  `viewer.scene.pick(new Cesium.Cartesian2(309,306));`.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for the reminder.

Comment: For anyone else following this, it was resolved here: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/cesium-dev/oshCTkW_INk/1-YyhtxmBgAJ